# Ncurses and TextBox

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

Does something like TextBox exist in ncurses?

Requirements to TextBox:

- ability to adequate handle KEY_DOWN, KEY_UP, KEY_LEFT, KEY_RIGHT, KEY_BACKSPACE, KEY_DC and other.
- adequate transfer lines.
- save, if you need, text in char* buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html) itself provides lower-level functions from which a "textbox" can be built.  For instance, the [`dialog`](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) and [`cdk`](http://invisible-island.net/cdk/cdk.html) libraries use (n)curses to provide these features.

Comment: @TomasDickey, Yes, I started to realize it myself, but stumbled on a couple of points. However, thanks anyway. This is what I need.